# Trying to replace height and width values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to replace height="" and width="" values in a string($content) with PHP, i've tried preg replace to no avail, 
and suggestions on what i'm doing wrong?

Sample content would be:

```
$content = '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/c0sL6_DNAy0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

Code below:

```
if($type === 'video'){

        $s = $content;
        preg_match_all('~(?|"([^"]+)"|(\S+))~', $s, $matches);

        foreach($matches[1] as $match){

            $newVal = $this->_parseIt($match);
    preg_replace($match, $newVal, $s);

        }

    }
```

Here i just take the match and search for my height and width

```
function _parseIt($match)
{
    $height = "height";
    $width = "width";

    if(substr($match, 0, 5) === $height){

        $pieces = explode("=", $match);
        $pieces[1] = "\"175\"";

        $new = implode("=", $pieces);
        return $new;

    } 

    if(substr($match, 0, 5) === $width){

        $pieces = explode("=", $match);
        $pieces[1] = "\"285\"";

        $new = implode("=", $pieces);
        return $new;

    }

    $new = $match;
    return $new;

}
```

There's probably a much shorter way to do this, however, I really just picked up programming 6 months ago.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Line 3 on _parseIt() should be $height = "height";

Comment: right, thanks. and  if(substr($match, 0, 5) === $height) should reflect ($match, 0, 6) got it.

Comment: You may need to elaborate. Replace what with what? Do you want to strip height= and width= numbers, or add them, or replace them? -- The parseIt workaround is quite fiddly. You could do that with a single `preg_replace('/ (width|height)="\d+"/', ' $1="200"', $src)`

Comment: id like to take whatever is numeric value is inside the ="" and replace them with my own values...

Comment: Thanks Mario, definitely had me going in the right direction!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace`.  It can take an array of regular expressions that you want to match and an array of replacements.  You want to match `width="\d+"` and `height="\d+"`. (If you're parsing arbitrary html, you'll want to extend the regex to match optional whitespace, single quotes, etc.)

```
$newWidth = 285;
$newHeight = 175;

$content = preg_replace(
   array('/width="\d+"/i', '/height="\d+"/i'),
   array(sprintf('width="%d"', $newWidth), sprintf('height="%d"', $newHeight)),
   $content);
```

Comment: Excellent and worked just as you mentioned. Thanks, I can only hope to be as good , one day.

Comment: I need to do this with CSS % and px values. Does this work inside such values?